# Got error when deploy adapter in mfpdev

Tags: cordova, maven, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am working on IBM MobileFirst platform 8.0 when i deploy the created adapter i get some error.I am new here.Please help me.
this is the error i got.I can create the adapter successfully.But i could not deploy it, When i deploy it i got those error.My MFPDEV version is 8.0.0-2016101416

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
com.ll:two:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin is
 missing. @ line 44, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building two 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:deploy (default-cli) @ two ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.670 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-16T17:57:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:d
eploy (default-cli) on project two: Error accessing http://localhost:9080/mfpadm
in/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters: D:\mars2\workspace\newproject.app\
two\target\two.adapter (The system cannot find the path specified). Check proper
ties details in pom.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception

Error deploying adapter
undefined
Error: An error occurred during an attempt to deploy the adapter. See the preced
ing messages for details.
```

Comment: 1) Provide your exact build version of MFP 8.0.
2) What is your mfpdev version?
3) There are only warning seen. What error did you face and did your adapter deploy fine?

Comment: Hi, I edit the post with full content what i got in the cli. Please check and reply

Comment: `Error accessing http://localhost:9080/mfpadm
in/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters: D:\mars2\workspace\newproject.app\
two\target\two.adapter (The system cannot find the path specified)` Is `two.adapter` at that location? Is the server URL correct? You might need to post your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that the version of your plugin

> adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701

Is quite newer than your devkit version

> 8.0.0-2016101416

There have been some significant changes/improvements/fixes over the past 4-5 months, one of which requires that the server be up to date with the dev environment.  Please try upgrading your devkit/server to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same issue was to double check that in the `adapter.xml` the `<JAXRSApplicationClass>` (for adapters) or the `class` in the `securityCheckDefinition` (for Security Checks) exists and it has the same name as the .java class